# Convert String to Float in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, parsing, jstl

I have a field `price` stored as a String, and I would like to do an operation on this field in JSTL, is there a way for me to do this? I tried using `<fmt:parseNumber var="price" type="currency" value="${item.price}" />` which seems to give me an error[1], where my price is `"0"`. I also had tried `number` for the type but I want it to be converting to float/double.

[1]

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "0"
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:385)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.ParseNumberSupport.doEndTag(ParseNumberSupport.java:164)
```

Any ideas what I can do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for currency formatting we need to pass currency symbol as below try this

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" value="${product.price}" />
```

Comment: I just tried using `${product.price * 10}` without formatting it first or anything, and also `price` here is still a string and it seems to compute these operators without even parsing?? So there is no need to parse anything apparently.